# Optimize constructor call

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a raw instance of a class with the method:

```
FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject
```

Later I fill the data of the instance and execute the parameterless constructor with:

```
paremeterlessCtor.Invoke(instance, null);
```

I just call the parameterless constructor for the user to have control of the initialization process of the object. But the problem this two functions are expensive (yes I timed them out). I used to have an optimized version of this but without the user having control over the initialization of the object and caching the delegate instead of calling Invoke directly (to avoid reflection), thing is I need to invoke the constructor which is `ContructorInfo` type and not `MethodInfo`, so I can't make a delegate out of it, neither I can make a `pre compiled expression`. So how I can avoid using the Invoke overload for calling the constructor?

Also is there any other method more efficient than `GetUninitializedObject`?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** The raw instance its for a type resolved in runtime for an ORM library, not that I need one, but I like to reinvent the wheel and its all done, but I just want to optimize the Invoke ctor for avoiding reflection (if possible). I know that I can create a Initiliaze method for this, but i feel the constructor its semantically more adequate for the initialization process by the user when the mapping its done.

Some formatted piece of code if its needed for understanding what I need to optimize:

```
private static List<DerivedType> internal_getAllRows<DerivedType>(SelectorMode mode) where DerivedType : TemplateInstance
{
//Create a raw instance of the generic type to be mapped
instance = (DerivedType)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(DerivedType));
//Fill the raw instance with relational data
instance.initializeRaw();
instance.initialize(typeof(DerivedType));
//Get the parameterless constructor
var ctor = typeof(DerivedType).GetConstructor(Types.EmptyTypes)
ctor.Invoke(instance, null); //Invoke the constructor on the mapped instance, I am trying to avoid reflection HERE !
}
```

Comment: Why not simply implement an interface which exposes an `Initialize` method? Calling the constructor after you initialized it already seems a very bad practice (in fact, aren't you it calling twice now)? Voting to close since we need to see more code to analyze what your current code is doing.

Comment: This is for a ORM where the default constructor is called either by the library with a defined state (lets say mapped) or by the user itself in a "create new" state. So whenever the library maps from DB the user needs to have the control and i dont know if anything feels more adequate than the constructor... But thats unreleated to the question, not that i want to change my method, i just want to know how i can avoid reflection for the Invoke overload.

Comment: But what are you creating before calling the constructor then? Where is that code?

Comment: A instance type resolved in runtime... like i say its for a ORM so types are registered in the library and later you can map them from DB. Its all generic if you still need the code i can put it on the question.

Comment: This question goes very deep into reflection. For people who are voting for closing it down: It is a valid question, for me it is a clear question. But I understand it is not clear for all, because they do not understand the deep matter. Please do not close a question, or vote it down, when you do not have the knowledge to udnerstand it.

Comment: Can't `new()` be added to `DerivedType`? Then you can just `new` it directly. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx)

Comment: @MartinMulder I do get the inner working of this. It just seems very bad practice to me and want to know why OP chooses this approach.

Comment: That would create a new instance and i already have the instance with filled data, i just need to invoke the constructor without creating a new instance, and since constructors are not really creating the instance (only the CLR .new) it should be valid, and it is thanks to this overload:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But i cant apply some caching optimization like precompiled expressions or delegates since Constructors are ConstructorInfo type and not MethodInfo

Comment: Your only argument is that for another developer it is more convenient to write logic in a constructor? This seems a lot of trouble for that.

Comment: Seems more convenient to complement an defined state like "mapped" into the constructor where semantically its for populate data members and that is exactly what i want, there are some relational data that the user would like to store in properties or fill a filtered list with relational data, you name it. Initialization method just doesnt seems right but its a solution anyway (that i dont like)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have once created this method to create a delegate to a constructor. It is not an 100% solution for you, but is might give you a start. I will edit this answer later today!

*** EDIT ***

Finally, it works (with the help op de OP!):

```
public static Action<T> CreateDelegate<T>(this ConstructorInfo constructor)
    where T: class
{
    if (constructor == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("constructor");

    // Create the dynamic method
    DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod(
        constructor.DeclaringType.Name + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", ""),
        typeof(void),
        new[] { typeof(T) },
        constructor.Module,
        true);


    // Create the il
    ILGenerator ilGenerator = method.GetILGenerator();
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // Copy the reference to the instance on the stack.
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, constructor); // Call the constructor.
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); 

    // Return the delegate :)
    return (Action<T>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T>));
}
```

Comment: This is so a good start... i will test the performance for this later in the day, but i think caching the delegate will always be faster than reflection.

Comment: True. Delegate-calls are always faster than Reflection-calls. You should create the delegate once, store it, and use it as much as you need. My original method has an internal caching mechanism. I removed that one from the code, since it does not part of your question, since storing the result can also be done somewhere else.

Comment: @MartinMulder, doesn't `newobj` create a new instance? The OP wants to call the ctor on an existing instance. I've been trying to do that in IL, without success so far.

Comment: Your new code doesn't work either, it throws a VerificationException (operation could destabilize the runtime). I tried that too, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: I know... hence my remark "still not working". :)

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Nope. Yesterday I continued my work :p It is still acking. I feel this is the right way, but I am missing something. I simply need a bit more time to finish this last step.

Comment: The IL seems to be good i dont know what is the problem, been trying different ILs and none work... i will put a bounty on this question tomorrow, hope you can solve it

Comment: Got it working, i edited your answer with the working example nothing out of this world, just minimal changes, i still will give you the accepted answer cause you did most of the work and thanks again

Comment: @ffenix, well done! I had tried the same IL and it didn't work, apparently it just needed the module in the DynamicMethod creation.

Comment: Now for optimizing the GetUninitializedObject thats a whole new level of problem, i already research a little and i cant find the CIL opcode for allocate a new instance without calling the constructor... Anyway the GetUninitializedObject its still pretty fast.